# Install Windows Driver with Wix - DifxAppExtension - unexpected child element 'Driver'

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm using WIX toolset to install our application, while trying to install a device driver using the following XML snippet

```
 <DirectoryRef Id="AFolder"> 
  <Component Id="ADriver" KeyPath="yes" Guid="*">
    <Driver Legacy='yes' />
    <File Id="CM.inf"  Source="CM.inf" Vital="yes"/>
    <File Id="CM.sys"  Source="CM.sys" Vital="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

It fails with the follow error - "The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'Driver'."

I did add a reference to difxapp_x64 to my wix project, and also add xmlns:difx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension to the Wix Element.

I'll appreciate any suggestions to the right direction/solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<difx:Driver Legacy='yes' />
```